# Node.js setInterval lifetime

Tags: node.js, cron, setinterval

How long can a setInterval last in node.js. I need to use it as a cron job. I don't care if the server restarts and resets the interval, important thing is not to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setInterval` runs until it is stopped using `clearInterval` or something forces it like you said a server restart. If the server restarts and resets the interval it just starts again. Have a look at this link [here](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) this might help you if you are trying to have a cron job.